# Best strategy to check harddisk issues on Red Had Linux

Tags: linux

What is the best strategy(and utility) to check hard disk related issues on red hat Linux ?

Comment: Is this really programming related?

Comment: Running the S.M.A.R.T. daemon is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the issue.  If it's some sort of failure-related thing, check `dmesg` for error messages and `smartctl` for info on what might have gone wrong.  If it's performance problems, check `smartctl` for remapped blocks and `sar -d 1 0` to see how hard the disk is actually being thrashed.

Beyond that, what issues are you actually having?  More detailed questions elicit more detailed answers.